# Turning a list of lat/long in an array into assoc array of lat/long

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Using PHP,

I want to turn something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => -27.61797
[1] => 153.31181
[2] => -27.61801
[3] => 153.31183
[4] => -27.61806
[5] => 153.31188
[6] => -27.61824
[7] => 153.31217
[8] => -27.61826
[9] => 153.31246
[10] => -27.61783
[11] => 153.31324
)
```

Into:

```
Array
(
[0]
   [lat] => -27.61797
   [long] => 153.31181
[1]
   [lat] => -27.61801
   [long] => 153.31183
[2]
   [lat] => -27.61806
   [long] => 153.31188
[3]    
   [lat] => -27.61824
   [long] => 153.31217
[4]
   [lat] => -27.61826
   [long] => 153.31246
[5]    
   [lat] => -27.61783
   [long] => 153.31324
)
```

This is needed so I can pass a list of lat/long to mapping API so I can display a path in my iOS and Android apps.

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: Yes, about 10+ ways to try and figure it out.. its got to the point that its now 2:20am and I can't figure it out. Any help appreciated. Otherwise, I'll try with fresh eyes in the morning.

Comment: Have you tried the `array_chunk($your_array,2);`?

Comment: Well, your best attempt as a code would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

assumin that the array $myArray contain sequence of lat, lng
you can use a for loop with step 2 for build the $newArray as you need

```
  $numCoords  = count($myArray)/2
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numCoords; $i++ ){
    $newArray[$i]['lat'] = $myArray[$i*2]; 
    $newArray[$i]['long'] = $myArray[($i*2)+1]; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($your_array); $i += 2) {
    $new_array[] = ['lat' => $your_array[$i], 'long' => $your_array[$i + 1]];
}
```

A sophisticated one:

```
$keys = ['lat', 'long'];
$new_array = array_map(function($v) use ($keys) { return array_combine($keys, $v); }, array_chunk($your_array, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do it using `array_chunk()`

```
<?php
$array = [-27.61797,153.31181,-27.61801,153.31183,-27.61806,153.31188,-27.61824,153.31217,-27.61826,153.31246,-27.61783,153.31324];
$chunked  = array_chunk($array,2);
foreach($chunked as $k=>$v){
    $final[$k]['lat'] = $v[0];
    $final[$k]['long'] = $v[1];
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($final);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/981915